# Oracle Dynamic sql: Updating column with apostrophe value

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to update a column using dynamic query. The updating value has an apostrophe (PEOPLE'S REPUBLIC OF CHINA~ THE). I'm getting the below error.

```
/*Example Table Data*/
CREATE TABLE CUST_DATA
  (
  ID number,
  LEGAL_ENTIRY_ID   VARCHAR2(50),
  CUST_ID           VARCHAR2(50),
  CUST_NAME         VARCHAR2(50)
  );
INSERT INTO CUST_DATA VALUES(1,'ICC02','CH001','TEST123');
INSERT INTO CUST_DATA VALUES(1,'ICC02','LN001','TEST456');
/
CREATE TABLE RR1
  (
  ID                VARCHAR2(50),
  ADJUSTMENT_VALUE  VARCHAR2(50)
  );
INSERT INTO RR1 VALUES('CH001',q'[PEOPLE'S REPUBLIC OF CHINA~ THE]');
INSERT INTO RR1 VALUES('IN001','REPUBLIC OF INDIA');
INSERT INTO RR1 VALUES('US001','USA');
INSERT INTO RR1 VALUES('RU001','RUSSIA');
/
COMMIT;

/*PLSQL Block*/
DECLARE
TYPE T_VARCHAR  IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
V_CUST_ID       T_VARCHAR;
V_ADJ_VALUE   T_VARCHAR;
V_TABLE_NAME    VARCHAR2(30);
V_SQL             VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT ID,ADJUSTMENT_VALUE BULK COLLECT INTO V_CUST_ID,V_ADJ_VALUE FROM RR1 ORDER BY ID;
    V_TABLE_NAME    := 'CUST_DATA';
    FOR I IN 1 .. V_CUST_ID.COUNT LOOP
        V_SQL := 'UPDATE '||DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(V_TABLE_NAME)||
                   ' SET CUST_NAME = '||DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(V_ADJ_VALUE(I))||
                 ' WHERE CUST_ID = '||DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(V_CUST_ID(I));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_SQL -->'||V_SQL);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR -->'||SQLERRM||' / '||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
END;

ERROR -->ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error / ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 342
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 411
ORA-06512: at line 11
```

The 'CUST_NAME' column is being updated with "PEOPLE'S REPUBLIC OF CHINA~ THE". Please let me know if there is a workaround for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bind variables then all your problems are solved (incl. better performance and risk of SQL-Injection):

```
V_SQL := 'UPDATE '||DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(V_TABLE_NAME)||
        ' SET CUST_NAME = :CustName '||
        ' WHERE CUST_ID = :CustId';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL USING V_ADJ_VALUE(I), V_CUST_ID(I);
```

For non-dynamic statement you can also use:

```
INSERT INTO RR1 VALUES('CH001','PEOPLE''S REPUBLIC OF CHINA~ THE');
```

I am not 100% sure (i.e. I did not test it) but you may run the update in a single statement like this:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE T_ADJUSTMENT_REC IS RECORD (
      ID RR1.ID%TYPE,
      ADJUSTMENT_VALUE RR1.ADJUSTMENT_VALUE%TYPE );
   TYPE T_ADJUSTMENT_TYPE IS TABLE OF T_ADJUSTMENT_REC ;
   T_ADJUSTMENT T_ADJUSTMENT_TYPE;

   V_TABLE_NAME    VARCHAR2(30);
   V_SQL             VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

   SELECT T_ADJUSTMENT_REC(ID,ADJUSTMENT_VALUE) 
   BULK COLLECT INTO T_ADJUSTMENT 
   FROM RR1 ORDER BY ID;
   V_TABLE_NAME    := 'CUST_DATA';

   V_SQL := 'UPDATE (SELECT CUST_NAME, CUST_ID, ADJUSTMENT_VALUE FROM '||V_TABLE_NAME||
           ' JOIN TABLE(:t) ON ID = CUST_ID) SET CUST_NAME = ADJUSTMENT_VALUE';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL USING T_ADJUSTMENT;

END;
```

Perhaps there is also a solution with [FORALL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321), I never used FORALL in dynamic SQL (with bind variables).